# How to make Custom Marquee in our react native app?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to make Marquee for our react-native app. I already tried many third party library. But all the library contains only one direction i.e. right-to-left, but I want to make marquee for both directions. Below is my code, I also tried react-native-reanimated library for making custom marquee, but not works. Please help

```
// Marquee.js file
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Animated, {
  useSharedValue,
  withSpring,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useAnimatedScrollHandler,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
 
const Marquee = ({ text, direction }) => {
  const scrollX = useSharedValue(0);
  const scrollRef = useRef(null);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (scrollRef.current) {
      scrollRef.current.scrollTo({ x: direction === 'left' ? 500 : -500, animated: false });
      scrollX.value = direction === 'left' ? 500 : -500;
      scrollRef.current.scrollTo({ x: 0, animated: true });
    }
  }, [direction]);
 
  const scrollHandler = useAnimatedScrollHandler({
    onScroll: (event) => {
      scrollX.value = event.contentOffset.x;
    },
  });
 
  const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      transform: [{ translateX: withSpring(scrollX.value, { stiffness: 50 }) }],
    };
  });
 
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Animated.ScrollView
        ref={scrollRef}
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        onScroll={scrollHandler}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
      >
        <Animated.View style={animatedStyle}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>{text}</Text>
        </Animated.View>
      </Animated.ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};
 
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    overflow: 'hidden',
    width: '100%',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});
 
// App.js File 
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Marquee from './Marquee';
 
const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Marquee text="This is a left-to-right marquee" direction="left" />
      <Marquee text="This is a right-to-left marquee" direction="right" />
    </View>
  );
};
 
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default App;
```